# How play music for alarm app in ios6?

Tags: ios, ios6

How play music in my alarm app from musiclibrary in ios6 ?

Is there a new API or new feature UILocalNotification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only new in the standard Clock app, the API (MediaPlayer) has been around for a while.

Here's some links:
[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
[A tutorial on TutsPlus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-music-library-access/)